# Wine not launching applications on Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: kubuntu, wine, games, lutris

I installed stable Wine from the site's repository but when I launch games (Monkey Island Special Edition) they show the black loading fullscreen then they crash. I tried even with Lutris. This happens on all of the 3 PCs I installed Wine/Lutris and even tried with other games/apps but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Have you tried PlayOnLinux? It will install any dependencies you may need to play your games.

Comment: No, I install everything manually, I mean the Direct X and VC. It's all up to date and I'm careful with the settings. In fact on Kubuntu 20.10 it all ran flawlessly. I don't know what happened. Maybe there are some conflicts due to the implementation of Wayland (I still use X11).

Comment: Hi, sorry, no I was _suggesting_ you use PlayOnLinux! It'll make it a lot easier and may install a dependency you don't know you're missing.

Comment: Upgraded to 21.10 now Wine works but Lutris can't launch games because DXVK doesn't work. Tried to disable it but every single game gives me an error at startup. Never really worked with my 2x Nvidia GTX680 SLI even though the new Nvidia drivers claimed to fix DXVK issues. Even on Steam/Proton it worked a few months then stopped working (the only game I have to test is MGSV, it runs smoothly for 10 minutes and then crashes!).

Comment: Yesterday I played MGSV two times for more than 15 minutes without crashes or freezes then today I created a match and froze after 7-8 minutes! Steam client is updated to latest version and there weren't any proton updates in these 2 days. I cannot figure out what the problem could be. Maybe Konami bans Linux players? I use TOR and I2P with DNSCrypt but if this was the case it should pop-up a notification telling me I'm banned but the game freezes instead!